# Attempting to unfollow a question will remove it from bookmarks

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-interface

I noticed an odd behaviour of the user interface. If I follow and bookmark a question and later try to remove the question from the *followed posts* list on the user page, the bookmark is removed, not the followed post. The button also changed to *remove bookmark* in the *followed posts* interface. I don't know if this is intentional, but it wasn't what I wanted to do.

[image: bookmarks/followed post]

Comment: That looks so weird. That looks like two speech bubbles, right? One speech bubble which points to the ellipse and one speech bubble to explain the first speech bubble.

Comment: It's also really irritating that when you unfollow there is no visible change of state of the item in the list. There ws highlighting functionality removed when the new list templates were poorly implemented

Comment: This bug seems to be resolved by the recent updates to evolve bookmarks to saves. I don't know if an answer or adding a tag would be appropriate.